# How to add slide transition in dropdown menu of navbar in boostrap 4 with vue js transition

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, nuxt.js

I am trying to add slide up and down the transition on the bootstrap 4 dropdown menus using vue transition.

The transition is not working

I tried using the transition element but the animation is not working.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
         For Individuals
        </a>
        <transition name="list">
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Income Tax Return</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">TDS</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Legal Services</a>
        </div>
         </transition>
      </li>

.list-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.list-enter-active {
  animation: slide-in .5s ease-out forwards;
}
.list-leave-to, .list-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: slide-out .5s ease-out forwards;
}
@keyframes slide-in {
  from { 
    transform: translateY(20px);   
}
to {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
}
@keyframes slide-out {
  from { 
    transform: translateY(0);
}
to {
  transform: translateY(20px);
}
}
```

The dropdown menu should slide in and slide out

Answer (score 2):

Vue will detect and apply the transition only for some conditions. Please read [Transitioning Single Elements/Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Single-Elements-Components). So in this case I think `v-show` is our best choice.

So your template should be something like:

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <transition name="menu">
      <div class="dropdown-menu" v-show="show">
        <a class="dropdown-item">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you have to trigger `show` variable when Bootstrap show and hide dropdown. You can do this by listen to `show.bs.dropdown` and `hide.bs.dropdown` events:

```js
let dropdown = $(this.$el).find('.dropdown')
let menu = $(this.$el).find('.dropdown-menu')

dropdown.on('show.bs.dropdown', () => {
  this.show = true
})

dropdown.on('hide.bs.dropdown', () => {
  menu.css('display', 'block') // This prevent element hide before animation
  this.show = false
})
```

[Live Example](https://jsfiddle.net/aj75v9bu/)

Note: In this example I use `margin-top` to make animation instead of `transform` because Bootstrap is already used `top` and `transform` for the position of dropdown menu.

Comment: And how about if I want to add hover feature over navbar menu items ?

Comment: I don't understand. Could you explain more?

Comment: I am trying to implement hover effect on the navbar menu items of bootstrap i.e if the mouse pointer is over the navbar menu items the dropdown should open and closed when mouse pointer leaves.  I am unable to do transition on multilevel submenus can you help me in this? https://jsfiddle.net/divzdave/7h8xauw4/